# main method not found in class Main

Tags: java, eclipse, program-entry-point

I am trying to run this class but I am getting an error that main method is not found although I have defined the `public static void main (String [] args){}`

This is my class file :

```
package jDBCLearn;

public class Main {
  public static void main(String[] args) {

    try {
      Connection connection = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306", "root", "Ronitpandey123");
      System.out.println("Connection Succesful");
    } catch (SQLException e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
    }
  }
}
```

This is the project explorer:

[image: Image of project explorer]

This is the error log :

```
Error: Main method not found in class jDBCLearn.Main, please define the main method as:
   public static void main(String[] args)
or a JavaFX application class must extend javafx.application.Application
```

This is the run configuration:

[image: Image of run configuration]

This is the dependencies folder:

[image: Dependency folder image]

This is the source folder:

[image: image of source folder]

Comment: I really cannot understand this error the main method is already present still it is throwing this error . Please tell me how to fix this  error

Comment: Try and clean your build before running again.

Comment: is that the only error? see this exclamation mark [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2xSbs.png) - it often indicates some (project) configuration error - check the `Problems` view if there is some error there (I also wonder the `.classpath` entry under Dependencies)

Comment: To troubleshoot this, it via the cli but first compile it `javac src/jDBCLearnProject/Main.java` and then run it via `java src/jDBCLearnProject/Main.java`